How to add rounded corners to a non rectangle table?
I used tabularray package to create the following table, which is not of a rectangle shape. I would like to draw this table with rounded corners. As I understood I can do that either using nicematrix package (which uses tikz for the lines) which I don't know it or either using tikz package to create the table from the beginning. Is there any way using tikz as wrapper to have this table with rounded corners, or is there any way just using the tabularray package to do that? Here is my MWE:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={180mm,257mm},left=15mm,top=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray,ulem}
\begin{document}
        \begin{tblr}{columns={l,5cm},rows={h,5cm},row{2,4,6}={5mm,m},vline{2-4},vline{1}={1-4}{2pt},vline{4}={1-6}{2pt},hline{1}={1-3}{2pt},hline{7}={2-3}{2pt},hline{5}={1}{2pt},vline{2}={5-6}{2pt},cell{2,4}{1-3}={r,font=\scriptsize},cell{6}{2-3}={r,font=\scriptsize}}
        \cline{1-3}
        $34859+5975$&$17135-2986$&$20000-15627$\\
        (p.5)&(p.10) &(p.10) \\
        \cline{1-3}
        $729\cdot58$&$882\div42$&$2838\div27$\\
        (p.10)&(p.10) &(p.10) \\
        \cline{1-3}
        &{\Huge$\uparrow$} \uline{text}&{\Huge$\uparrow$} \uline{text}\\
        &(p.10) &(p.10) \\
        \cline{2-3}
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}



Have a look at tcolorbox + raster library

Thanks! I will.

With {NiceTabular} of nicematrix and TikZ to draw the heavy frame.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={180mm,257mm},left=15mm,top=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Small}{m}{\Block[R]{}{\scriptsize #1\enspace}}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ll|l}[columns-width=5cm]
  $34859+5975$&$17135-2986$&$20000-15627$\\[5cm]
  \Small{(p.5)}&\Small{(p.10)} &\Small{(p.10)} \\ \Hline
  $729\cdot58$&$882\div42$&$2838\div27$\\[5cm]
  \Small{(p.10)} & \Small{(p.10)} & \Small{(p.10)} \\ \cline{2-3}
  &{\Huge$\uparrow$} \uline{text}&{\Huge$\uparrow$} \uline{text}\\[5cm]
  &\Small{(p.10)} &\Small{(p.10)} \\ 
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \draw [rounded corners, very thick] 
     (1-|2) -| (last-|last) -| (5-|2) -| (1-|1) -- cycle ; 
  \tikz \draw (1-|2) -- (5-|2) ;
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}


